# C#2.0 read and copy Xml file line by line?

Tags: c#, xml, file-io, c#-2.0

I got an Xml file `fileOri.xml` and there are some lines like

`<SubItem name='somename' value='someVal'></SubItem>`

and I plan to copy these lines to another file `fileDes.xml`. Is there a rapidly & easily way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Rajs answer, here's how you can do it using Transform:

**The code**

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\fileOri.xml");
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\fileDes.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("C:\\MyStylesheet.xslt");
transform.Transform(reader, writer);
```

**The Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- define the root element for your destination document -->
        <xsl:element name="root">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//SubItem">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Doing it via Transformation gives you the flexibility to change the content you like to copy without touching the executable in the future - just modify the Xslt to your needs.

---

**Hint**

Your question suggests that you probably rather want a flat text file with line items for further processing - in that case you can still use Xslt but with text output.

Comment: @Nano, You're welcome. I'll update the sample code to allow for using a Xslt transforming into Xml or CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Load the XML in a XmlDocument object
2. Use an XPath like //SubItem to get all SubItem elements
3. Create a new XmlDocument object
4. Loop through the nodelist obtained in step 2 and write out the elements.

However, you can also use a stylesheet and then use transform to create the new xml.

Comment: Transforming would be the best solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the whole file, use File.Copy

If you want to copy some of the nodes, open the source using `XmlDocument`, run zpath query on it using `SelectNodes`, iterate on resulting node collection and copy each node's `.OuterXml` to new file.